# Call function with parameters

Tags: ios, function, swift, parameters

I'd like to call a function, which has parameters, from another function. This is the function which should be called: `func saveDate(notiz: Notizen){}`. I tried this: `saveDate(notiz: Notizen)`but I'm getting an error. `Notizen` is a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make this call with an instance of `Notizen`, e.g.

```
let notizen = Notizen() // Depends on how you create an instance of Notizen
saveDate(notizen)
```

Note, that the first parameter name is not used, unless you specify it, e.g.

```
func saveDate(#notiz: Notizen) { }
```

Would require you to write

```
saveDate(notiz: notizen)
```

Answer (score 4):

Compiler is right you should pass instance of the class not class itself:

```
let noti = Notizen()
saveDate(notiz: noti)
```

But if saveDate function is fiction declared as you shown inside the class you should drop the notiz word:

```
let noti = Notizen()
saveDate(noti)
```